# getView() returning textview but textview is not updating

Tags: android

I have a fragment A that extends B. Inside of B I init my views in the `onCreateView` like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    mView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    mText1 = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView1)
    mText2 = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView2)
    retrun mView
}
```

but in my text update method if I try to get the `mText1` like this (I know can you use the `mText1` field from before but that is not the point)

```
public void updateView()
{
  mText1 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  mText1.setText("test");
  mText2.setText("test");
}
```

Notice that I use `getView()` to get `mText1`. On the screen strangely only the `mText2` is set and `mText1` is totally blank!!??

Edit: Additionally if I switch to another fragment then come back both mText1 and mText2 will not get updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a static reference from a 3rd party library that was keeping the old fragment alive :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one Fragment active that defines a textview as R.id.textView1, then you are probably finding a textview somewhere else in the view hierarchy.  You're not getting a NullPointerException when you call setText(), so findViewById() is returning something.

Since getView() returns the root view for the Activity, findViewById will find the first view with that id.

Try using mView.findViewById(...) to restrict the search to just the views within your fragment.

Comment: This is a good guess but not the problem. I added addition information above. This problem also happens when i come back to the fragment but then none of the views work